# WSO2: Enriching a OM property node value

Tags: wso2

I have an empty OM property like so:

```
<property description="empty extra_data" name="extra_data" scope="default">
    <extra_data xmlns=""/>
</property>
```

Later on, I want to add data to this XML structure.

First enriching – adding the child element works fine:

```
<enrich description="set URL child in extra data">
    <source clone="true" type="inline">
        <url />
    </source>
    <target action="child" xpath="$ctx:extra_data"/>
</enrich>
```

Next, I want to set the URL that is stored in another property ("url").
I've tried it like that but it doesn't work (invalid target):

```
<enrich description="set url" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <source clone="true" property="url" type="property"/>
    <target xpath="$ctx:extra_data//ns:url/text()"/>
</enrich>
```

Can anyone help me with that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. Set the XML tag and its content in a property and append it as a new child element.

```
<property description="url xml tag" expression="fn:concat('&lt;url>', $ctx:url, '&lt;/url>')" name="url_xml" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<enrich description="set url child in extra data">
    <source clone="true" property="url_xml" type="property"/>
    <target action="child" property="extra_data" type="property"/>
</enrich>
```

I still would've liked to replace or set a value inside a node, but that works for now...